# Append before the last element while creating dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

```
     var creatediv = document.createElement("div");

    var text1 = '<input id="attribute1" type="text" placeholder="Attribute" />    
    $(creatediv).append(text1);


    var text3 = '<input id="attribute3" type="text" placeholder="Attribute" />
    $(creatediv).append(text3);


    var Label = '<label id="label1"> test </label>';
    $(Label).Insertbefore(text3);
    $(creatediv).append(Label);
```

Am creating div with the above method and appending textbox and lable as shown above. my problem is when i try to append Label.

I need to append label in the same way before the  text3 and make it it the div.

I can append after text1 but i don want to do that. How do i append and inserbefore in the above scenario ?

**When i append it automatically inserts in the last.
when i apply only insertbefore it is not appearing in my DOM.
how do i make this work !**
Thanks

Comment: not clear what you want to achieve , can you provide some visual hint how you want your elements to appea.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
$(label).insertBefore('#attribute3');
```

Comment: No by that way it is not making it in the DOM as it is not in the div

Comment: @Peru do you actually add your div to the dom at all?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it should be `insertBefore()` - note the lowercase `i`. Secondly, you are not appending the `div` you create to the DOM at all. Finally, your code is an odd mix of native JS, and jQuery. Try this instead:

```
var $div = $('<div />').appendTo('body'); 
// you can change where the div is appended above

var $text1 = $('<input />', { 
    id: 'attribute1', 
    type: 'text',
    placeholder: 'Attribute'
});
var $text3 = $('<input />', {
    id: 'attribute3',
    type: 'text'
    placeholder: 'Attribute'
});
$div.append(text1, text3);

var $label = $('<label />', {
    id: 'label1',
    text: ' test '
});
$label.insertbefore($text3);
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line `var Label = '<label id="label1"> test </label>';`

`$(creatediv).find('#attribute1').after($(Label));` 
OR

`$(creatediv).find('#attribute3').before($(Label));` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.
    var text1 = '';
    var text3 = $('');
    var Label = ' test ';

```
var container = $('<div></div>').appendTo($('body'));
container.append(text1);
container.append(text3);
text3.before(Label);
container.append(text3).before(Label);
```